# Rest API path with many to many relationship

Tags: spring, rest, api

I am defining a rest path for a many to many relationships. 
I want to get a list of users which are guest of a company.
Is the path below sufficient?

```
/api/v1/users/companies/{companyId}/guests
```

Because I put it in UserController so it cant not be

```
/api/v1/companies/{companyId}/guests
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I primarily intended to write a comment, but it's the way too long so I've written an answer instead.

First of all, REST is an *architectural style* and not a cookbook for designing URIs. REST doesn't enforce any URI design (as long as it's compliant with the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)) and it's totally up to you to pick the URIs that better identify your resources.

---

> Do you have any suggestion?

Answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. What you'll read from this point is my *personal opinion*.

If the *guests* and the *companies* resources can be managed independently, I would use the following mappings:

```
/companies
```

```
/guests
```

Then you can use a *query parameter* to filter the guests for a given company:

```
GET /guests?company={id} HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

To create a *guest* resource for a given company, you could use:

```
POST /guests HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "John Appleseed",
  "companyId": 1
}
```

Comment: I do understand that there is no rule for rest path design. I am looking for a good design. Your suggestion is great. I just applied it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your resource identifiers, so long as they are consistent with the production rules defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

```
/api/v1/users/companies/{companyId}/guests
```

That's fine

```
/api/v1/companies/{companyId}/guests
```

That would also be fine.

```
/d4158568-c40f-4c51-93cd-25642f6f42e2
```

So would that.

```
/api/v1/companies/guests?companyId={companyId}
```

On the web, you are perhaps more likely to see an identifier like this one; forms are a useful way of enabling a client to provide data, and HTML has production rules for creating a URI from data in a form.  Of course, HTTP also has mechanisms that allow you to [redirect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4) the clients attention from one URI to another, so you don't have to restrict identifiers to those appropriate for a specific client.

Comment: I think /api/v1/companies/{companyId}/guests is a better design than /api/v1/companies/guests?companyId={companyId}